# How to solve the logon issue in sql job?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have configured a sql job which backups the databases and then transfer them to a remote location in another step. On command prompt my command is working fine but when I schedule this in a job I found the error :

**Executed as user administrator. Logon Failure Unknown User Name or Bad Password. 0File(s) copied . Process Exit code 0. The step succedded.**

I want to solve these issue and I also want that if does get transferred then job should report failure but it doesn`t show any such message.

I just want that when no files get copied i.e. 0File(s) copied . it should notify failure job .

Thanks

Nitesh Kumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved . As the remote location folder was shared and was accessible to every one. My command was working fine from command prompt , even any user was able to create their own file on that location and also able to delete the file from that location.

The issue was related to user. My job was being executed by **servername\administrator** and remote location **administrator**  password was changed due to that bad password error occurred. I told my IT Team about the problem and they reset the server password as older one, and my job began to work fine.

The issue was solved.

I just want to know how my sql job authenticates the server login as I go through the script of my job and found nothing helpful regarding authentication.

Can any one explain it to me.

Thanks

Nitesh Kumar

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a `Script Task` to check if there is a file you want to copy. If there is one, the process can proceed, if not, the step can result in an error. You do this by adding

> Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;

to the end of the script task logic.

Anyways i dont know your package design so there might be more suitable ways.